# How to configure the various path options for webpack-dev-server if the index.html lies not directly in the output root?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

My setup uses webpack 4 with `html-webpack-plugin` and `webpack-dev-server`. The nature of my project is to produce a style library (deliverables are css, js, and further image files and font files if the need arises) and accompanying HTML documentation pages (intended audience are the devs that will use the style lib).
My output therefore has this structure:

```
dist
  |--production
  |    |--scripts    # flabbergastor.js
  |    |--styles     # flabbergastor.css
  |    |--fonts      # *.woff2 files
  |    |--images     # *.svg, *.png files
  |
  |--documentation
       |--parts      # all the parts needed for a multi-page doc done with static HTML
       |    |--pages # pages import f...tor.js and f...tor.css relative to this location
       |    |--styles
       |    |--examples
       |
       |--index.html # the entrypoint for anyone who is looking for guidance
```

The output is generated as expected, and when I start the dev-server with `$>webpack-dev-server --open` it serves the `dist` folder all right. But I can't for the life of me configure my `webpack-dev-server` to not look for a nonexistent `index.html` in the output root folder (`dist`) but instead just serve the entrypoint for the documentation which is `documentation/index.html`.
The relevant parts of my `webpack.config.js` are:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ...
  output: {
    filename: 'production/scripts/flabbergastor.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [...],
  },
  plugins: [
    ...
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'production/styles/flabbergastor.css' }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/documentation/index.hbs',
      filename: 'documentation/index.html',
      inject: 'head',
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    // pulling my hair out trying to figure out what goes here
  },
```

What I tried so far is all thinkable permutations of various path options:

```
output: {
  ...
  publicPath: ... // seems to have no effect, anyway the default is '/'
                  // and that seems about right regarding my output
},

devServer: {
  contentBase: ... // no effect,
                   // and is only meant to be used for non-webpack generated stuff
  publicPath: ...  // can only be used to offset the served output root folder

  index: 'documentation/index.html', // will serve the file, but...
                   // will cause the relative imports for css and js
                   // in this document to fail

  historyApiFallback: { index: '...' }, // no effect
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. It turned out that the option I need to use is [openPage](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserveropenpage).
We can either use this option inside the `webpack.config.js` like so:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ...
  output: ...
  module: ...
  plugins: ...
  devServer: {
    openPage: '/documentation/index.html'
  },
}
```

Or we can use this option as a command line parameter to prepare a script in the `package.json` like so:

```
{
  "name": "flabbergastor-styles-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Foo MacFooface",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open-page /documentation/index.html"
  }
}
```